# Disabling +S filetype in Perforce

Tags: perforce

Perforce's filetype system includes the +S modified to denote that a file is a temporary file. The implication of this is that no file history is stored for that file - only the most recent version is maintained, and it is replaced with each new checkin.

This is obviously a dangerous flag to set accidentally, which we recently discovered. Is there a way to ensure that this is not used in the future?

Comment: Did the person who accidently set the flag give any explanation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a pre-commit trigger that looks at the file list for this flag, rejecting the commit if this is the case.

See [this chapter of the Perforce manual](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4sag/06_scripting.html) for details.